# How to convert a string to an array of chars in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Let's say that you have a string `"Hello"` and you want an array of chars in return `["H", "e", "l", "l", "o"]`.

Although it's a simple question I couldn't find a direct answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several ways to get an array out of a String. `#chars` which is a shortcut for `thestring.each_char.to_a` is the most direct in my opinion

```
>> "Hello".chars
=> ["H", "e", "l", "l", "o"]
```

The are other ways to get the same result like `"Hello".split(//)` but they are less intention-revealing.